# L'« arrêt cardiorespiratoire » : être en, avoir, faire ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, verbes, locutions, santé-et-médecine

> *Deux participants en arrêt cardiorespiratoire à l’arrivée*
> Deux participants au demi-marathon Beneva de Montréal ont fait un arrêt cardiorespiratoire dimanche matin au fil d’arrivée. Ils ont été traités sur place et on ne craint pas pour leur vie. (ds. [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/grand-montreal/2023-09-24/marathon-beneva-de-montreal/deux-participants-en-arret-cardiorespiratoire-a-l-arrivee.php))

Est-ce qu'on **[(est) en]|a|fait** (un) *arrêt cardiorespiratoire* : lesquels se [disent](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/dictionnaire-des-cooccurrences/arret), lequel convient le mieux dans un tel contexte et pourquoi ou y a-t-il mieux ?

Comment: Et si c'était souple et qu'on pouvait dire les trois sans que cela ait beaucoup d'importance au niveau de ce qui est communiqué?

Answer (score 4):

Un arrêt respiratoire est à la fois un état (ici une pathologie) et une action (quelque chose qu'on fait). On retrouve les mêmes possibilités avec quelques autres mots ou expressions, par exemple :

- *Modérateur en grève*.  (titre, illustration, état)
- *Modérateur faisant grève*.  ( // , action)
- *Le modérateur [est|était] en grève*.  (état)
- *Le modérateur [a] fait [la] grève*.  (action)

---

- *Il est en guerre*. (état)
- *Il fait la guerre*. (action)

---

On peut employer l'un ou l'autre pour un arrêt cardio-respiratoire, les deux étant dans ce cas strictement synonymes puisque la volonté n'intervient pas.